# Keycloak authenticating to client and keeping a session open

Tags: keycloak

I have been struggling to get a POC working to use keycloak for SSO.

At its simplest, we have a web based react front end on nginx that talks to a resteasy based backend on wildfly and are looking to use keycloak to provide SSO authentication to the backend after using it to log in to the web frontend, with other backend services to be added later.

The "cors" example in the keycloak github repo seems the closest example to what we want to achieve, and has been the basis for my experiments so far. So a single realm with 2 clients set up for the front and backends on different IP addresses. The problem I am having is that each time the ajax request hits the backend it is starting a new session even though a JSESSIONID cookie is present in each request, but we need to keep a session alive and re-use it.

I have been struggling for a couple of days to try and work out what I am missing, and largely working on the assumption there is something I need to add to the ajax request but I have been unable to work out what so far.

Any ideas what I might be missing, how to convert the cors example to work with a session based backend, or any other examples that more closely match the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working I think. I added httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true; and it seems to be working now.

```
module.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('errorInterceptor');
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

Have i mentioned how much I hate browsers . . .